# Bloomberg API FX Forwards NDFs not returning prices

Tags: python, bloomberg

**Please** can anyone advise how I may retrieve **FX Forwards NDF's outright bid / outright ask or indeed any price data for USD/KRW for the 1W, 1M, 3M etc tenors**.

I have attempted to follow the DAPI instructions as well as attempting to find answers via Stackoverflow to no avail. I can however succesfully retrieve live bid asks for SPOT USD KRW or even Equities such as AAPL no problem

I have tried using different combinations of the tickers, although I see no error codes no actual live prices come back? Please does anyone have any ideas to get live ticking NDF outright prices:

**Any & all help is greatly appreciated :)** as Bloomberg seemingly don't provide any assistance

**['USD/KRW N 2M Curncy'], ['USD/KRW N 3M Curncy'] , ['USD/KRW N 3M ICAP Curncy']**

p.s the Excel Bloomberg formula such as **=BFxForward("USDKRW","3M","BidOutright")** is essentially what I'm trying to replicate via python, attempting to follow the DAPI instructions seems to not work.

I have used the C++ BLPAPI pdf examples to attempt to get this working however no NDF examples seemingly exist.

```
def main_subscribe():


tickers = ['USD/KRW N 2M Curncy', 'USD/KRW N 6M Curncy', 'USD/KRW N 9M Curncy']
fields = ['BID', 'LAST_BID_TIME_TODAY_REALTIME', 'ASK','MID']
interval = 2
options = parseCmdLine()

# Fill SessionOptions
sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
sessionOptions.setServerHost(options.host)
sessionOptions.setServerPort(options.port)

print("Connecting to %s:%s" % (options.host, options.port))
# Create a Session
session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

# Start a Session
if not session.start():
    print("Failed to start session.")
    return

try:
    # Open service to get subscription data from
    if not session.openService('//blp/mktdata'):
        print("Failed to open '//blp/mktdata")
        return

    # init subscriptions
    subs = blpapi.SubscriptionList()
    flds = ','.join(fields)
    istr = interval and 'interval=%.1f' % interval or ''
    for ticker in tickers:
        subs.add(ticker, flds, istr, blpapi.CorrelationId(ticker))
    
    session.subscribe(subs)

    # Process received events
    while(True):
        # We provide timeout to give the chance for Ctrl+C handling:
        ev = session.nextEvent(900)
        for msg in ev:
            print(msg)
        # if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA:


        #     try:
        #         for msg in ev:
        #             #print(msg)
        #             print(f"{fields[0]}:{msg.getElementAsString(fields[0])} , {fields[3]}:{msg.getElementAsString(fields[3])} , {fields[2]}:{msg.getElementAsString(fields[2])} , {fields[1]}:{msg.getElementAsString(fields[1])}")
        #     except Exception as e:
        #         print(e)
        #         #print(msg)
        #         None
        
finally:
    # Stop the session
    session.stop()
```

This is the output when main-subscribe is run:

```
CID: {[ valueType=POINTER classId=0 value=0000024DBF510CB0 ]}
RequestId: -----------------------------
MarketDataEvents = {
MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE = SUMMARY
MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE = INITPAINT
API_RULES_VERSION = 201411210
SIMP_LAST_PX_ALL_SESS_DIR_RT = 1
SMART_FIELDS_METADATA_VERSION_RT = "21.10.08.02 "
IS_DELAYED_STREAM = false
MID = 1.000000
RT_API_MACHINE = "apipubx0@----------"
RT_YLD_CHG_NET_1D = 0.000000
IND_BID_FLAG = false
IND_ASK_FLAG = false
BASE_PRICE_ENABLED_RT = false
EVT_DELTA_TIMES_RT = 0
ALL_PRICE_COND_CODE = ""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `KRW <Curncy> FRD <Go>` screen in the Bloomi Terminal:

[image]

If you hover the mouse over the 3M outright Bid (in the circle), the pop-up shows the underlying ticker to be `KWN+3M BGN Curncy`.

When I put this ticker in Excel as:
`=BDP("KWN+3M BGN Curncy","BID","UpdateFrequency",500)` then I get updating bid side pricing which matches the Terminal screen.

Since the underlying DAPI for Excel and Python is the same, I would guess that this ticker will work with the blpapi too. I usually find it is quicker to test tickers and fields in Excel.

Comment: I'm tremendously grateful for your help & assistance. I have used "KWN+3M BGN Curncy" as the ticker that the following code subscribes to: "for ticker in tickers:
            subs.add(ticker, flds, istr, blpapi.CorrelationId(ticker))
        
        session.subscribe(subs)" This works perfectly :) I will most certainly follow your advice going forward to ensure that I hover over the element /data point I'm interested in to get its appropriate ticker. thanks soo much

Comment: @Py_trader No worries. Bloomberg naming conventions are pretty much a mystery!

Comment: are you aware if we can also subscribe to interpolated tenors such as the "4M" or "4Y" Tenors that are greyed out in Bloomberg? In excel the interpolated values are returned however when attempted to use the same ticker naming convention as above No values are returned. we can manually use pandas to interpolate but not precisely the same as the bloomberg interp function. Thanks again for the above :)

Comment: @Py_trader My very limited knowledge of FX has doubled already while looking into this, so I don't have an answer I'm afraid. Looking at the bid/offer, I don't imagine differences in interpolation methodology would have much impact. You can probably replicate whatever interpolation Bloomi uses. From the Terminal it suggests Bloomi just uses linear interpolation unless you ask for cubic.

Comment: + or indeed if we can retrieve the settlement date of the successfully returned tenors, I tried adding "SETTLE_DT" as a field we want to subscribe to however it comes back as NAN"

Comment: Thanks very much @DS_London :) much appreciated

Comment: Did you try SETTLEMENT_DATE_RT? The field SETTLE_DT is valid, just not for real-time: it only updates once a day. You can get the non-RT ie 'static' data also using the blpapi from the `refdata` service (which also has DAYS_TO_MTY which might be useful for interpolation). The way to find all this out is to type `KWN+3M BGN Curncy FLDS <Go>` in the Terminal. You can then search for fields, and filter on Field Type (RT, Static etc).

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much SETTLEMENT_DATE_RT did the trick, you're better than Bloomberg themselves :) , thank you